# Why are edits not saved on custom field profile?

Tags: custom-fields, profile

Drupal 7.41
Civi 4.6.9

I've inherited this site recently and see an issue with custom field profiles that I haven't seen before.

Custom field set is tied to contacts with corresponding profile.

When editing the custom field set from the contact page, edits are saved correctly.

However, when I edit them from the profile, nothing is saved.

There are no errors that I can see in any logs.

I've cleared the templates_c folder to no avail.

All users have access all custom data permission.

After more research, if I add a built-in Civi field (like last name) to the profile and edit it, the last name edit is saved but no custom field data is saved.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any required fields?  Sounds a little similar to https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17247

Comment: One testing profile does not have any required fields and one does.  Same outcome regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the error was due to contacts that were tied to disabled sub-types.

They had created a few sub-types some time ago, added individuals of that type and then disabled the sub-type.

Once I enabled them, they were able to edit using the custom field profiles.

Since they weren't using them, I created a profile to bulk edit their sub-type and pretty quickly cleaned things up.